# Matching the best regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, match

In following table, how can I match '`FG2-4G4T5`' so that the first returned row is the best match (which would be '`FG2-4G`')?

```
part_match
^FG2|^FF2|^FF3-S|^FF4-GR
^FG2-4G
^FG2
 FG2-RGST
```

The following query doesn't work in this case because '`^FG2|^FF2|^FF3-S|^FF4-GR`' has greater length:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE 'FG2-4G4T5' REGEXP part_match ORDER BY length(part_match) DEC
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoops, sorry @hsz for blowing your edit away... I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your part_match is ALWAYS of the form ^xxxx and optionally EQUAL-SIZED ^yyyy|^zzzz|...

```
SELECT * FROM parts
WHERE 'FG2-4G4T5' REGEXP part_match
ORDER BY instr(concat(part_match,'|'),'|') DEC
```

This will give you the longest matching prefix.

To solve the inclusion of FULL matches, take one off the length of part matches, so,

```
SELECT * FROM parts
WHERE 'FG2-4G4T5' REGEXP part_match
ORDER BY CASE WHEN part_match LIKE '^%' THEN -1 else 0 end +
         instr(concat(part_match,'|'),'|') DEC
```

To solve REGEX involving multiple sections of unequal length, e.g. `^YYYY|^Z|ABC`, you will first need to find a function that breaks that into multiple rows

```
part_match    | single_part
^YYYY|^Z|ABC    ^YYYY
^YYYY|^Z|ABC    ^Z
^YYYY|^Z|ABC    ABC
```

Then REGEXP by single_part referencing back the part_match in the answer.  This is non-trivial but can be achieved with a Numbers table and judicious use of SUBSTR and INSTR.

Create a numbers table (run this once):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateNumbersTable;

delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateNumbersTable()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  drop table if exists Numbers;
  create table Numbers (N int primary key);

  SET @x := 0;
  REPEAT 
    insert into Numbers values (@x);
    SET @x := @x + 1;
    UNTIL @x > 999 END REPEAT;
END//
delimiter ;

CALL CreateNumbersTable;

DROP PROCEDURE CreateNumbersTable;
```

Then you can use this query

```
select p.*
#  ,substr(p.part_match, N.N+1, locate('|', concat(p.part_match,'|'), N.N+2) -N.N -1)
#  ,length(substr(p.part_match, N.N+1, locate('|', concat(p.part_match,'|'), N.N+2) -N.N -1))
from parts p
inner join numbers N on N.N between 0 and length(p.part_match)
  and ((N.N = 0) or (substr(p.part_match, N.N, 1) = '|'))
WHERE 'FG2-RGST' REGEXP p.part_match
  and 'FG2-RGST' REGEXP substr(p.part_match, N.N+1, locate('|', concat(p.part_match,'|'), N.N+2) -N.N -1)
order by length(substr(p.part_match, N.N+1, locate('|', concat(p.part_match,'|'), N.N+2) -N.N -1)) DESC
```

Uncomment lines 2 and 3 to see the parts of part_match it matches on.

Comment: Thanks. There are also full part match  (i.e. 'FG2-4G4T5' may also be in the table)

Comment: They are also not equal sized

Comment: yeah sorry.....This is a huge table, and it was bad designed from the beginning. Now I that the company has grown a lot; this is now a problem. I want to avoid having to use  C++ to fix this.

Comment: Works amazing. I merged with an other query (there other parameters that decide  which row to choose) and works really well. This was of a system that we have on C++. I will keep it on beta but so far works well and the logic makes sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: I replaced
'inner join number'

by
INNER JOIN (SELECT @row := @row + 1 as N FROM parts AS counterTable,
(SELECT @row := -1) tempTable) AS Numbers

This removes the need of creating a temporary table, and reduces the load on our mysql db (as this query is run a lot on the manufacturing floor)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the K.I.S.S. solution is best. Keep another column that lists the actual length of text matched by the pattern?

```
part_match           part_match_length
======================================
^FG2|^FF2|^FF3|^FF4  3
^FG2-4G              6
^FG2                 3
```

and thus...

```
SELECT * FROM parts
WHERE 'FG2-4G4T5' REGEXP part_match
ORDER BY part_match_length DEC
```

Technically, the second column doesn't even have to necessarily be length - just some kind of indication of how good a match a given pattern provides.

Comment: Thanks.I cant this has thousands and maybe millions of entries

Comment: If you can programmatically determine the lengths (for instance - selecting each pattern, splitting on `|`, and looking for the longest substring), then you could have a script to create the column for you. Just because it's a separate column doesn't mean you have to enter it manually.

Comment: A single part_match can contain multiple lengths, and you would need to identify which component of the `|||` is the one that matched. This solution won't work